How to dynamically add a thread or pick a thread from the pool of thread in python
I'm looking to schedule tasks to be executed by threads, with the ability to dynamically add or remove tasks from the process. My goal is to pre-create a pool of threads, for example, [th1, th2, th3], and then assign tasks (e.g., t1, t2, t3) to these threads via an API call to my system.
When I receive a task like t1, I want to select a random thread from the pool and assign this task to it.
So far, I've experimented with ThreadPoolExecutor in Python, but it doesn't seem to provide a way to dynamically add or remove tasks from an already running process.
Note: The tasks I'm dealing with are event listeners that run continuously until I decide to stop listening to the event bus. Therefore, I thought having a pool of threads from which I can pick and assign event listener tasks would be beneficial.

def run(task_arg):
    # core logic of the listener which continuously listens for the 
    # events

def using_executor():
    argument_dicts = [
        {"topic": "/captureSaveEvent"},
    ]
    logging.basicConfig()

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
        futures = {executor.submit(run, arg): arg for arg in argument_dicts}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            try:
                future.result()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Thread for {futures[future]} failed with exception: {e}")


In the above I have defined the task to be submitted in argument_dicts but I want to add a task to this same process by adding a new thread or picking a thread of the thread pool and assign the task to it, I don't want to create a new process and create new threads for every new task I want to add, since the task are listener events which won't exit, so the process which created the threads will continue to be active as long as I quit the listener or some issue in the listener logic.
What I expect is, I need to know the process id, and using that pid, I should be able to pick a thread from this process which is free to take new tasks and submit the job to it.

Actually I don't quite understand why a thread pool is unable to fulfil your needs. If my understanding of your problem is correct, all you need to do is to set up a server process that hosts a threadpool object and a queue for external process to send commands to it. Maybe if you have a sample code of your system and the relevant API, I can understand your problem better.

Let's get our terminology in synch. You have a single process running multiple threads in a pool (using, for example, concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) to which you can submit multiple tasks When you say that ThreadPoolExecutor doesn't seem to provide a way to dynamically add or remove tasks from an already running process, I don't know what you mean by an "already running process." You certainly cannot remove a task after it has been submitted. Do you mean to ask how to add/remove more threads to the pool to handle additional submitted tasks so they can all run concurrently?

@R_M_R, show your code (or a minimal reproducible example of it)

This answer is based on the following requirements I gathered from your descriptions:

A pool of threads to run tasks
A task should run continuously until ordered to stop
Thread pool can accept command to run/stop a task

The solution will involve creating a task manager thread to handle the thread pool and accept/remove tasks.
from threading import Event, Lock, Thread

def task_func(arg, stop_event):
  while not stop_event.is_set():
    # core logic of the listener which continuously listens for the 
    # events

class TaskManager(Thread):
  def __init__(self, workers_count: int = 20):
    super().__init__(daemon=True)

    self.workers_count = workers_count

    self.__new_tasks = []
    self.__lock = Lock()
    self.__task_stop_events = {}
    self.__stop_event = Event()

  def run(self):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=self.workers_count) as executor:
      while not self.__stop_event.is_set():
        with self.__lock:
          for task in self.__new_tasks:
            stop_event = Event()
            executor.submit(task_func, task[1], stop_event)
            self.__task_stop_events[task[0]] = stop_event

          self.__new_tasks = []
        
        time.sleep(0.001)  # prevent task manager from hogging resource

  # add new task to run
  def start_task(self, task_id, task_arg):
    with self.__lock:
      self.__new_tasks.append((task_id, task_arg))

  # stop currently running task
  def stop_task(self, task_id):
    with self.__lock:
      if task_id in self.__task_stop_events:
        self.__task_stop_events[task_id].set()
        del self.__task_stop_events[task_id]
          
  def stop(self):
    self.__stop_event.set()

Example usage of the task manager:
tm = TaskManager()
tm.start()  # start the task manager thread

...

tm.start_task('task_1', {"topic": "/captureSaveEvent"}) # add a task

...

tm.stop_task('task_1') # stop a task

...

tm.stop()  # stop task manager thread

